# Trying to display data from a database in HTML tags using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a function in my home page that will change the content of an article in HTML from placeholders to info from a database before the page loads.  However I keep getting an error saying that I'm missing a formal parameter.  What have I done wrong?

The HTML:

```
<article id="article1">
    <img src="images/sadface.png" alt="The image didn't load, sorry" id="img0">
    <h4 id="heading0">Not working</h4>
    <p id="p0">This item hasn't loaded, sorry</p>
    <script>
        window.onload = function splashFunction(0);
    </script>
</article>
```

And the Javascript:

```
function splashFunction(x){

document.getElementById("img" + x).src="images/cart2.jpg";

document.getElementById("heading" + x).innerHTML="cart";

document.getElementById("p" + x).innerHTML="cart";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change your DOM with a call to your database you will have to use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), I hope you know that.

As for your code, you are defining the `function` again on `window.onload`. To call the function just use its name, as such:

```
window.onload = splashFunction(0);
```